# How to show all of aspecific post type that has taxonomy and a specific term

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, customization, custom-post-type-archives

i have a post type called directory_listing, i have a taxonomy called 'place' and I have terms in that tax for place1 and place2. I need to display all the 'directory_listing' posts that use the term place2 of taxonomy 'place' in a custom page template.

this is as far as i got, i am lost.

```
<?php
$pages = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'directory_listing',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'place',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => ('place2'),
      'include_children' => false
    )
  ))
);

foreach ($pages as $page) {
      echo $pages->post_title . '<br/>';
      echo $pages->post_content . '<br/>';
      echo $pages->slug . '<br/><br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: `numberposts` is long since deprecated. Use `posts_per_page` and the parenthesis around `the-damn-bar` are not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why that `$pages` suddenly became `$myposts`!!? Anyway, I really don't see any big issues with your code, however, you can try this..

```
<?php
$pages = get_posts(array(
  'post_type' => 'directory_listing',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'tax_query' => array(
    array(
      'taxonomy' => 'place',
      'field' => 'slug',
      'terms' => 'place1',
      'include_children' => false
    )
  ))
);

foreach ($pages as $page) {
      echo $page->post_title . '<br/>';
      echo $page->post_content . '<br/>';
      echo $page->slug . '<br/><br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: ahh yes I just caught that, tired eyes i suppose. ThankYou

Comment: Now, say i need to populate the 'terms' specifically to each page. would using a custom field writing to that area work?

Comment: @Joe Can you please explain a bit more on what you are trying to achieve? If you want to display archive for a specific term in a specific page, you can create a page template containing a loop to display posts from that term. Or even better, take advantages of Template Hierarchy http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Taxonomies_display

Comment: Abhik, I just want to have a place for the user making the page to add the term data, so above where is says place1, from the wp page editor. Like if there was a custom field on the page editor where they could just type 'place1' so that page would give all the results using that term. Does that help?  I know you cant echo a custom field shortcode in place of 'place1' in an array.